# Extra Advantage of Using Amazon SES over plain nodemailer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nodemailer

What is the extra advantage of using Amazon SES as transport facility. I can achieve the same using plain nodemailer, what extra advantage do I get If I use SES as transport facility in my nodemailer. Can somebody please clarify.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guys, Why -2 for question and +2 for answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services like Amazon SES, Mailchimp, Mailgun, etc. help you when you have a large traffic of email going out from your application. Using Amazon SES you can scale easily whenever you want and it can handle a large traffic. The delivery percentage is also very high.
In the plain nodemailer way your own server(architecture) has to take care of all of the above aspects. So if there are very few emails processes then go for plain nodemailer way.

I would always go for third party services like Amazon SES as they are inexpensive and easy to manage.

Comment: How can we estimate the system capability  with a nodemailer so that we can switch to SES.

Comment: I am not sure how you can do that on your architecture. Check the link below. It might help you to achieve scalability on your server.
https://nodemailer.com/delivering-bulk-mail/

Comment: yeah, it helps. Thanks

Comment: The link I have provided in the previous comment gives 404. Please follow the following link
[https://community.nodemailer.com/delivering-bulk-mail/](https://community.nodemailer.com/delivering-bulk-mail/)